# SSIS Lookup Multiple Columns in one table to the same ID column in another

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following table:

```
EventValue | Person1           | Person2    | Person3     | Person4       | Meta1  | Meta2 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123        | joePerson01       | samRock01  | nancyDrew01 | steveRogers01 | 505   | 606
321        | steveRogers02     | yoMama01   | ruMo01      | lukeJedi01    | 707   | 808
```

I want to transform the Person columns into IDs for my destination table, so all of the ID's would be coming from the same `Person` table in my Destination DB:

```
ID | FirstName | LastName  | DatabaseOneID | DatabaseTwoID
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Joe       | Person    | joePerson01   | personJoe01
2  | Sam       | Rockwell  | samRock01     | rockSam01
3  | Nancy     | Drew      | nancyDrew01   | drewNancy01
4  | Steve     | Rogers    | steveRogers01 | rogersSteve01
5  | Steve R   | Rogers    | steveRogers02 | rogersSteve02
6  | Yo        | Mama      | yoMama01      | mamaYo01
7  | Rufus     | Murdock   | ruMo01        | moRu01
8  | Luke      | Skywalker | lukeJedi01    | jediLuke01
```

With results like so:

```
MetaID     | EventValue | Person1ID | Person2ID | Person3ID | Person4ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 123        | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4
2          | 321        | 5         | 6         | 7         | 8
```

I currently have a Lookup Transform looking up the first Person column, but couldn't figure out how to convert all 4 Person columns into IDs within the same lookup.

Comment: As per my understanding, you are looking for the results (table-3) using table1 and Table2 based on the Joining Table1.person1/person2/person3/person4 = table2.DatabaseOneID. Am I right? Are you looking for the script OR help regarding SSIS implementation way?

Comment: I actually have a script written for all the joins, but couldn't figure out how to do it via SSIS in VS. The actual table has about 10+ of these columns, all pulling the `PersonID` from my destination db. My best tryout was having 10+ lookup transforms

Comment: @mkRabbani so to answer your question: I'm looking for help regarding SSIS implementation. Sorry... I think I rambled

Comment: Hmm, I can not help you regarding SSIS. But one idea is, UNPIVOT table1 first so that all Person1-4 values come to one column. Then JOIN with your Lookup table to collect Person IDs. Then PIVOT the result again to bring back the result to previous format.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one query, or use `UNPIVOT`, or use a scalar function if you think it'll be more fixable for your implementation. Then, you just create a view of it, in which it'll be an easy access for you.

here is a quick example :

```
DECLARE 
    @tb1 TABLE 
(
    EventValue INT
, Person1 VARCHAR(250)
, Person2 VARCHAR(250)
, Person3 VARCHAR(250)
, Person4 VARCHAR(250)
, Meta1 INT 
, Meta2 INT 
)

DECLARE 
    @Person TABLE 
(
    ID INT 
,   FirstName VARCHAR(250)
,   LastName  VARCHAR(250)
,   DatabaseOneID VARCHAR(250)
,   DatabaseTwoID VARCHAR(250)
)


INSERT INTO @tb1 
VALUES 
(123,'joePerson01','samRock01','nancyDrew01','steveRogers01',505,606),
(321,'steveRogers02','yoMama01','ruMo01','lukeJedi01',707,808)


INSERT INTO @Person 
VALUES 
(1,'Joe','Person','joePerson01','personJoe01'),
(2,'Sam','Rockwell','samRock01','rockSam01'),
(3,'Nancy','Drew','nancyDrew01','drewNancy01'),
(4,'Steve','Rogers','steveRogers01','rogersSteve01'),
(5,'SteveR','Rogers','steveRogers02','rogersSteve02'),
(6,'Yo','Mama','yoMama01','mamaYo01'),
(7,'Rufus','Murdock','ruMo01','moRu01'),
(8,'Luke','Skywalker','lukeJedi01','jediLuke01')

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EventValue) AS MetaID, *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.EventValue 
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN t.Person1 IN(p.DatabaseOneID, p.DatabaseTwoID) THEN p.ID ELSE NULL END) AS Person1ID
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN t.Person2 IN(p.DatabaseOneID, p.DatabaseTwoID) THEN p.ID ELSE NULL END) AS Person2ID
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN t.Person3 IN(p.DatabaseOneID, p.DatabaseTwoID) THEN p.ID ELSE NULL END) AS Person3ID
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN t.Person4 IN(p.DatabaseOneID, p.DatabaseTwoID) THEN p.ID ELSE NULL END) AS Person4ID
    FROM @tb1 t
    LEFT JOIN @Person p 
        ON p.DatabaseOneID IN(t.Person1, t.Person2, t.Person3, t.Person4)
        OR p.DatabaseTwoID IN(t.Person1, t.Person2, t.Person3, t.Person4)
    GROUP BY t.EventValue
) D
```

Answer (score 0):

> I currently have a Lookup Transform looking up the first Person column, but couldn't figure out how to convert all 4 Person columns into IDs within the same lookup.

You cannot do this within the same lookup, you have to **add a Lookup Transformation for each Column**. In your case you should add 4 Lookup Transformation.

---

If source database and destination database are on the same server, then you can use a SQL query to achieve that as mentioned in the other answer, but in case that each database is on a separate server you have to go with Lookup transformation or you have to import data into a staging table and perform Join operations using SQL.